# unable to login with facebook in django

Tags: python, django, facebook, authentication, facebook-graph-api

I am not beig able to login with facebook from LOCAL HOST 8000.I tried all the steps listed in some tutorials.Please take a look at my code and help me with this

I tried all the answers in stackover flow

I'm posting my settings.py

```
import os
# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See     https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'rg9n#$ebfj4w_mv-%7aahi2!qnitgw%xt(4re%i&)vdlppnz^e'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True
SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = False
# Honor the 'X-Forwarded-Proto' header for request.is_secure()
#SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')
# Force HTTPS in the final URIs
SOCIAL_AUTH_REDIRECT_IS_HTTPS = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1','localhost',]


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'togther',
    'django_select2',
    'corsheaders',
    'collabmates_api',
#    'mail_templated',
#    "fcm_django"
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'social_django.middleware.SocialAuthExceptionMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'project.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
        os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'social_django.context_processors.backends',
                'social_django.context_processors.login_redirect',
                'django.template.context_processors.media',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'project.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'test_database',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': '61437',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-                validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME':         'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidato    r',
    },
        {
        'NAME':         'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME':     'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
        },
    {
        'NAME':     'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'social_core.backends.facebook.FacebookOAuth2',
    'social_core.backends.linkedin.LinkedinOAuth2',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)   

SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_KEY = '65464654668654564'
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_SECRET = 'sa6g5asf54vafg5as5gf'
#SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_SCOPE = ['email','user_location','user_hometown']


SOCIAL_AUTH_LOGIN_URL = ""
SOCIAL_AUTH_LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = "dashboard"
SOCIAL_AUTH_LOGIN_ERROR_URL = "error"

SOCIAL_AUTH_LINKEDIN_FIELD_SELECTORS = ['email-address', 'headline', 'industry']
# Arrange to add the fields to UserSocialAuth.extra_data
SOCIAL_AUTH_LINKEDIN_EXTRA_DATA = [('id', 'id'),
                                   ('firstName', 'first_name'),
                                   ('lastName', 'last_name'),
                                   ('emailAddress', 'email_address'),
                                   ('headline', 'headline'),
                                   ('industry', 'industry')]

EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.sendgrid.net'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'mahesh'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'example@gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True


CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
```

And i have added "https://localhost:8000" to facebook developers site url's page , also added "localhost" to APP DOMAINS, and "https://localhost:8000/oauth/complete/facebook/" to the redirect uri's

let me know if you want me to update any additional information.thank  you

Comment: delete the question and repost it with all the secret keys id's and important thing with ******* or else black them  before posting

Comment: edit the question with the error you're encountering.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook requires a domain name.

Set a domain in your hosts file (I don't know how to do this on Windows or Apple) but on Linux it is in `/etc`

Add something like `127.0.0.1  development.com` and give Facebook the domain name development.com and work in your browser from `development.com:8000`

Comment: `'URL blocked: This redirect failed because the redirect URI is not white-listed in the app's client OAuth settings. Make sure that the client and web OAuth logins are on and add all your app domains as valid OAuth redirect URIs.` this is the error im getting

Comment: You need to enter the valid redirects in your Facebook app

Comment: i added this `https://development.com:8000/oauth/complete/facebook/`..is it wrong..or does i have to add something else

Comment: I have all these:  https://localhost:8000/https://localhost:8000/complete/facebook/https://developmet.com:8000/https://development.com:8000/complete/facebook/http://development.com:8000/http://development.com:8000/complete/facebook/http://development.com:8000/complete/facebook/login/callback/http://development.com:8000/accounts/facebook/login/callback/

Comment: dont we have to separate each of those with commas? i'm new to this , please  dont mind for my stupid questions